# xib vs iPhone : distorted, overlapping objects

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios-simulator, xib

The below image explains all.
[image]

Why are the objects overlapping on the simulator?? how do I make them both of the same size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The top-level view in your xib is using the iPhone 5 screen size, but you're running the simulator in the iPhone 4 screen size, which is shorter.  Since your xib appears to be using autolayout, you need to adjust the constraints on your objects so that the objects are repositioned and/or resized the way you want for the smaller screen size.